# External links don't open in cordova inapbrowser

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

The inappbrowser opens, but it shows just a white page but the url is correct. What's my mistake?

```
$scope.goToLink = function (url) {
           window.open(url, "_blank", "location=yes");
    }
```

html

```
  <a ng-click="goToLink(card.link)"><i class="fa fa-globe redicon fa-2x"></i></a>
```

config.xml

```
  <access origin="*" />
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
  <access launch-external="yes" origin="mailto:*" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Comment: Do you have a content security policy meta tag in your index.html for your app and what does that look like please?

Comment: check if the url value is present inside the function or not

Comment: Is whitelist plugin installed ?